# How do I hide credentials.json on web?

Tags: json, web, google-api

I am trying to use the google apis on web.
And there is a credentials.json to access your api.

However, I am worried about that the credentials.json is public in web and people can access my json file though developer console.

Is there anyway to hide the credentials.json file to public?